# how to display parent items with their child items in mysql database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using the MySQL database. I have table with following data and table name is account:

```
    id       name      parent-id
     1       aaa          null
     2       bbb          1
     3       ccc          2
     4       ddd          1
     5       eee          3
```

i would like to display as follows

```
      names
       aaa
         bbb
            ccc
               eee
         ddd
```

I have tried a lot but I doesn't get exact requirement.

Comment: read this doc http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

This will involve quite a bit of work, may not be too scalable, but here are the steps from what I had done similarly.

1.Determine the maximum depth the child can go upto. ( Is it 3?), i.e., how deep the farthest child can go away from the root. Call this maxlevels.

2.Find the level for each row, call this myrowlevel

3.Pad the name with no. of spaces equalling (maxlevels - myrowlevel) or its multiple.

Comment: You will need to first answer the question: How many levels of children will the data go upto ? (Or should it be planned for infinite?) . Even then, my expertise lies in Microsoft SQL Server, but will try in MySql.

Comment: thank u for reply the levels of children may be infinite

Comment: Hmm.. then I think you should go with Girish's comment above that mentions Mike Hilly's article. I'll try and see if I can write sample code for your case based on it.

Comment: i have go through mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql this link but i have a confusion to determine left and right node numbers how can i calculate node numbers from select query

Comment: @Michael can u please help for this question